# Distributed cache file retrieval issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-streaming

My question may sound stupid, but I am new to Hadoop map reduce. So its  difficult for me to figure out.

I am implementing K means clustering in map reduce and using Cloudera CDH4 (4.1.1). 
 
The data consists of points with x and y coordinates. Thus, I am updating the centroid at each step until the change in all of the centroids is less than 0.1.

So for first iteration, I put the sample centroid file in distributed cache using

```
if (iteration == 0) {
    Path hdfsPath = new Path(input + "/centroid.txt");
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(hdfsPath.toUri(), conf);
} else {
    Path hdfsPath = new Path(again_input + "/part-00000");
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(hdfsPath.toUri(), conf);
```

For the next iteration, I am fetching the again_input directory which is same as the output for first iteration, in which I stored the newly calculated centroids

However the mapper is again fetching the centroid file which it fetched for first iteration. 
Below is the code to fetch the centroid file in mapper class:

```
Path[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
BufferedReader cacheReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cacheFiles[0].toString()));
```

Doubt 1: Does Distributed Cache clears all the files once job is done or does it keep them? For e.g. centroid.txt is cleared after iteration 1.

Doubt 2: Am I accessing the correct file?

Comment: centroid.txt is cleared after 1 st iteration and for next iteration the .txt file will get updated

Answer (score 0):

In this case are you reusing the Configuration class object `conf` in the iteration?

I think that is the issue. Can you please check which all files are added into distributed cache of the second iteration job?

You can do that by iterating through the Path[] Array

```
Path[] cacheFiles;
```